# How can I test Existing app on Phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I already have installed app on device, how can I use XAMARIN UI TEST for test it ? I don't need to reinstall or install apk on my Android.

Answer (score 0):

For testing with `Xamarin.UITest`, iOS requires that you link in either the  `Xamarin Test Cloud Agent` for `Xamarin.iOS` application projects or linking in the `Calabash` agent in your ObjC/Swift Xcode project for "native" applications.

> Non-Xamarin.iOS apps are also supported by Xamarin.UITest, but instead of the Xamarin Test Cloud Agent require linking Calabash.

- https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A-How-to-add-Calabash-to-Xcode

So for existing iOS application that are **not linked** to the `Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent` or the `Calabash` framework, Xamarin.UITest` **can not** be used.

Testing frameworks like `Appium` can be used on existing native, hybrid and mobile web app iOS applications as it uses Apples' **UI Automation framework** (which `Xamarin.UITest` does not use).

Comment: sorry, I mean - installed on Android Device